# Multithreaded Python script calling C++ subprocess: speed/performance issue

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I am currently writing a Python script to run simultaneous simulations of sporting events (let’s say for argument’s sake that they are tennis matches; it could be other sporting events or even option prices from a given list of stocks). At the moment, my script allocates a thread for each event, calling a function which contains a `subprocess` call (via `POpen`) to a C++ executable (i.e. the simulation). There is also a `logging` instance that is shared between the threads to collect status messages relating to the simulation output and some other functions manipulating that output, as well as error messages when there is faulty input data.

Somewhat predictably, I find that the simulation time for each event increases as the total number of events increases. I have been looking at a couple of options to alleviate this problem:

- Initially, I thought that the issue arose from the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) and tried to wrap my C++ code using the `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` macros to release the GIL. I never got it to work, always getting an error message that a `tState` couldn’t be found.
- I considered using `multiprocessing` (or `concurrent.futures`) instead of `threading`. But I can see at least two problems with this change of approach. First, there could be situations where the number of events I have to simulate concurrently well exceeds the number of cores available on my computer (e.g. there could be 30-40 concurrent tennis matches at a given time). Second, there could be issues in trying to maintain a common `logging` instance across several concurrent processes.

So, I have two sets of questions:

- Is the “thread macros” solution viable in this case? If so, what could I be doing wrong to get this missing `tState` error message?
- Would `multiprocessing` (or `concurrent.futures`) resolve my problem, despite the constraints I have outlined? If not, what other option(s) could be available?

Comment: Lot of resources out there for processes to waste time fighting over. RAM, disk access, network bandwidth, maybe even pepperoni. Can't do much in the programming world without a steady supply of pizza.

Comment: So, it sounds like you've re-invented parts of the `multiprocessing` library using `threading`. The GIL is not really relevant here, as long as you aren't using blocking calls, and if you are using the `subprocess.Popen` constructor directly, then probably it isn't blocking. The issue is you can't just throw a bunch of processes / threads at your machine and expected it to scale indefinitely.

Comment: You actually already identified this very problem - "But I can see at least two problems with this change of approach. First, there could be situations where the number of events I have to simulate concurrently well exceeds the number of cores available on my computer (e.g. there could be 30-40 concurrent tennis matches at a given time)." That is **already** a problem with your approach.

Comment: Use a pool to tune this, keeping a maximum number of workers running. Empirically test how the performance scales with more workers. don't re-invent the wheel, use the standard library e.g. [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor `](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor)` with your `subprocess.Popen` approach. since you dont need python code to run in seperate processes, no need to use a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` [Read the example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example)

Comment: I suspect isn't much you can do to alleviate this past a certain point -- i.e. the number of cores. The other option - get more horses. You can use a 256 gigabyte RAM machine with 64 vcpus instance on Amazon for 3 dollars an hour.

Comment: You could monitor your operating system - are all cores at 100%? If so, you are best off making sure you don't run too many processes at once - they tend to thrash memory. A ThreadPool with number of workers a bit less that cpu count, each doing a waiting call to Popen would be a good choice.

Comment: Its also possible that this C++ program uses a bunch of threads, so you'd reduce the concurrency count even more.

Comment: Do you have some kind of time requirement for returning the results? Otherwise you can stick "matches" in a queue and have them be processed by one or more processes, possibly on different machines. This will optimally use all available resources and can further be enhanced to auto-scale your pool of workers.